# A question about an abelian subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is a non-abelian group and $G_1 \le G, G_2 \le G$.  $G_1$ and $G_2$ are cyclic subgroups of $G$, and hence, are abelian.  Is it true that $g_1 g_2 = g_2 g_1$ where $g_1 \in G_1$ and $g_2 \in G_2$ since $G_1$ and $G_2$ are abelian?

Answer (score 4):

No. Consider any non-abelian group and elements $a,b$ such that $ab \neq ba$. Now, consider the subgroup generate by $a$ and the subgroup generated by $b$ (call then $G_a$ and $G_b$ respectively).

Then, $G_a$ is cyclic and $G_b$ is cyclic (hence abelian). However, by construction, we have that $ab \neq ba$.